# JQGrid custom formatter not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jqgrid

I am trying to use a custom formatter for jqgrid in my Ruby on Rails application, but I am having terrible difficulty in getting it to respond.

Here is the function I am using:

```
function YNFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject)
{
     var color = (cellvalue >= 10) ? "green" : "red";

    return '<span style="background-color:' + color + ';">' + cellvalue + '</span>';
}
```

However, my grid still displays, but without any formatting occurring.

Also, to give context, below is the rest of the jqgrid code for my index.html.erb with the above function included:

```
<div id="ItmDisplay"></div>

<table id="grid" class="jqInquiryGrid tblGen tblInlineEdit"></table>
<div id="gridPager"></div>


<script>
    $("#grid").jqGrid({
        url:'http://localhost:3000/ItmList',
        datatype: "json",
        altRows:true,
        altclass:'oddRow',

        jsonReader : {
          root:"itmdata",
          page: "currpage",
          total: "totalpages",
          records: "totalrecords",
          cell: "itmrow"
        },

        rowNum:10, 
        rowList:[10,20,30], 
        mtype: "GET",

        width:796,
        hidegrid:false,
        loadonce: true,  

        pager: 'gridPager',

        sortname: 'id', 
        viewrecords: true, 
        sortorder: "asc",

        search: true,

        height: 250,
        width: 600,
        colNames: ['Itm No', 'Title', 'Quantity', 'Category'],
        colModel: [{
            name: 'id',
            index: 'id',
            width: 30,
            sorttype: "int"},
        {
            name: 'title',
            index: 'title',
            width: 90,
            sorttype: "String"},
        {
            name: 'quantity',
            index: 'quantity',
            width: 90,
            sorttype: "float"},
        {
            name: 'category',
            index: 'category',
            width: 80,
            sorttype: "String"}
        ],
        caption: "Items List    ",
        // ondblClickRow: function(rowid,iRow,iCol,e){alert('double clicked');}
    });

function YNFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject)
{
    var color = (cellvalue >= 10) ? "green" : "red";

    return '<span style="background-color:' + color + ';">' + cellvalue + '</span>';
 }



    $("#grid").jqGrid('setGridParam', {ondblClickRow: function(rowid,iRow,iCol,e){loadForm(rowid);}});
```

```
<script>
// Global variable to hold the record id currently being dealt with 
item_id = 0;

// Function to load the edit form for a given id via AJAX
function loadForm(id) {
    path = "/items/" + id + "/edit"
    item_id = id;
    $("#ItmDisplay").load(path);
}

// function to return the current record id
function get_item_id() {
    return item_id;
}

$(document).delegate('form', 'submit', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
      var valuesToSubmit = $(this).serialize();

  // Rails path to pass the update request to    
   updatePath = '/items/' + get_item_id();

$.ajax({
  url: updatePath, //submits it to the given url of the form
  type: "post",
  data: valuesToSubmit,
  dataType: "JSON" 
}).success(function(json){ // the json variable holds the return from the server (JSON Object)
  //act on result.
  $("#ItmDisplay").text("Record Successfully Saved!!").fadeOut(3500);

  var $myGrid = jQuery("#grid");
  data = $myGrid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data');
  index = $myGrid.jqGrid('getGridParam', '_index');
  var rowId = json.id, itemIndex = index[rowId], rowItem = data[itemIndex];
  console.log(rowItem);
  rowItem.title = json.title;
  rowItem.quantity = json.quantity;
  rowItem.category = json.category;
  console.log(rowItem);
  $myGrid.jqGrid('setRowData',json.id,rowItem);

});
 });

</script>!
```

[jqrid output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kE2jA.png)

If anyone knows what I am doing wrong, your help would be very gratefully appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: RESOLVED:

Hey All, I have got this working now! Came across this approach on StackOverflow which was one I had seen previously while searching the site: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10653194/jqgrid-set-a-color-conditional-custom-formatter-based-on-row-values 

Thanks everyone who had a look at the above for me though, very much appreciated, and I hope this solution may help others too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see where you use `YNFormatter` in your code. You should specify `formatter: YNFormatter` for some column in `colModel`.

Another problem is the following: you use [background-color](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-color.asp) CSS style, but there are other CSS styles [background](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp) which applied from the parent elements. To see the background color one have to remove `background-image`. So one can fix the problem by usage `background-image: none` in combination with `background-color`. It's the main reason of the problem which you described.

The usage of formatter for setting of background color is not the best choice if you use no so old version of jqGrid. It's much better to use `cellattr` (see [my original suggestion](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/custom-cell-tooltips-used-title-property-of-colmodel-as-the-function/) to include the feature in jqGrid and [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12180842/315935) for example). The main advantage - you can set background color, but still use predefined formatter like `formatter: "date"` or `formatter: "float"`.

Some common remarks to the code which you posted:

- don't use `http://localhost:3000` prefix in the URL. Instead of `url:'http://localhost:3000/ItmList'` it's better to use `url:'/ItmList'`. It's not only shorter, but it's reduce possibility to make errors because of [the same origin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) restriction of Ajax.
- you should always add [gridview:true](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12519858/315935) option to your grids to improve performance.
- I recommend to use `pager` option always in the selector form `pager: '#gridPager'`. If you use the form `pager: 'gridPager'` or `pager: $('#gridPager')` jqGrid will have to "normalize" it and to change the option to `pager: '#gridPager'`.
- I recommend to use `autoencode: true` option if the data returned from the server contains pure *data* instead of HTML fragments placed in the grid's cells. The option make you sure that all texts returned from the sever will be correctly displayed even the texts contain symbols used for HTML markup.
- the property `sorttype: "String"` is unknown (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:colmodel_options)). The default value of `sorttype` property is `"text"`. It's better don't specify any `sorttype` property if you need the usage of text based sorting.
- you should remove `index` properties from `colModel` items which value are the same as the value of `name` property. By the way if you use `loadonce: true` the values of `index` have to be equal to the value of `name` property of some columns from `colModel`. So why to increase the code by including unneeded `index` properties? The shorter version of `colModel` seems to me better for reading:

```js
colModel: [
    { name: 'id',       width: 30, sorttype: "int"},
    { name: 'title',    width: 90 },
    { name: 'quantity', width: 90, sorttype: "float" },
    { name: 'category', width: 80 }
]
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks a mil Oleg for the all your assistance and for taking the time to write such a detailed response...hugely appreciated!! :) Thanks again! :)